# Why not get the value passed from the parent component to the child component correctly?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, angular-input

I need to pass a variable value from the parent component to the child component through an input. That is, the `screenMode` value received through the above `ng-container` needs to be given to the add-user child component.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="screenMode == screenStateEnum.ADD_USER || screenMode == screenStateEnum.EDIT_USER">

<add-user [screenMode] = "screenMode" [userId]="selectedRow?.userId" (goToUsers)="refresh()"></add-user>

</ng-container>
```

In add-user.component has `@Input() screenMode: string;` But this input always returns 0 for  EDIT_USER and 1 for  ADD_USER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These values imply that your `screenStateEnum` enum is a [numeric enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums) and looks something like this:

```
enum screenStateEnum {
  ADD_USER,
  EDIT_USER
}
```

If you want string values, you'd have to use a [string enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums). That could look something like:

```
enum screenStateEnum {
  ADD_USER = 'ADD_USER',
  EDIT_USER = 'EDIT_USER'
}
```

---

Of course you could also just change the type of your input field from:

```
@Input() screenMode: string;
```

to:

```
@Input() screenMode: screenStateEnum;
```